# What is faster performance wise: building a string by using + operator, & operator or via string.format?

Tags: vb.net, string, performance

what is faster performance wise: building a string by using + operator, & operator or via string.format?

varname, title, city, state, orgtype are variables I declared.

e.g.:

1.

```
varname = title + " in " + city + ", " + state + ". Contact " + title + ". " + orgtype + " " + city + "."
```

2.

```
varname = title & " in " & city & ", " & state & ". Contact " & title & ". " & orgtype & " " & city & "."
```

3.

```
varname = string.format("{0} in {1}, {2}. Contact {0}. {3} {1}.", title, city, state, orgtype)
```

Comment: You have forgotten to add the `StringBuilder` approach. Here's what Jon Skeet says: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html (note that you can apply anything that is said about C# on VB.NET as well)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That would be slower.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That would be slower than any of these approaches.  (he isn't using a loop)

Comment: @SLaks: Since he's asking about performance i assume that it's just an example and he actually has a loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: nope, no loop here. But good to know anyway. I see that SLaks answer takes this into account now. Thanks!

Comment: if there isn't a loop here then isn't the difference immeasurable/irrelevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two options compile to identical IL and are the fastest approach.

The third option will need to parse the string at runtime to find the `{}` pairs, making it slower.

---

Expressions like `a + b + c` will compile to a single `String.Concat(...)` call, without wasting any string literals.

The only time you should avoid ordinary string concatenation is insiude a loop, where the compiler cannot flatten it into a single call.
Instead, you should either replace the loop with LINQ and `String.Join`, or usea `StringBuilder`.